# wordpress custom error page or redirect to custom page in case of error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, error-handling

My site is in wordpress, I want to create custom message for any error in my site or want to show my custom page when site got any error instead of showing those error in site pages (if it is possible by redirecting to my custom page).

Errors means all types of error whether it is server (401,502,500...) related or PHP (syntax, fatal...) so whenever my site is not showing its original content in that case i want to display my custom page or message.

I have read articles on .htaccess, WP_CONFIG,ErrorDocument,Exception (PHP) but still not able get any solid solution for this.Hope this will clear my problem well.

Comment: By default, WP supports 404 error code errors. You may create a custom error handler in your theme functions.php to handle all error types. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: this page shows that "The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called"

Comment: What do you think when you deploy a products that have those errors types? In almost case, devs hive errors details in live env, show an error page and log the errors.

Comment: You can call your custom 404 page within theme using 404.php and this will used for wordpress internally like if entered url data  will not find in wordpress then call the 404 page, but if any fatal error then its not possible to call your page because your code is stopped in middle of .

Comment: Absolutely right, at this time if I redirect site url to my custom html page I not sure whether it is possible and if it is then how because if my basic site url is not working then how can I get access to any other static page. for example www.demo.com is not working because of fatal error then is it possible to www.demo.com/custom-error-page.html to run??